# Conducted EMI on power lines filter

Tags: emi-filtering

I've been looking around for answers for a while now and I haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone know how EMI filters are rated? The only specs I have been seeing use an attenuation curve or insertion loss curve to describe their filter but not much else. If I am getting noise on a power line how would be able to decide which filter would be able to screen it out? One of the filters I am looking at uses a spec sheet like this:
[image]

Am I to understand that anything under the attenuation curve is eliminated or is it something else? I'm sure that I am completely misunderstanding the situation, but I was hoping I could get some help.

Comment: The attenuation curve is in decibels, so for every 20dB "increase" in attenuation, the amplitude at that frequency is cut by an additional factor of 10.  E.g.: -60dB = 0.001.  The selection of the filter depends on what noise exists at the input and how much noise you can tolerate at the output.

Comment: Exactly as @vir said.  You need to know what the noise that's coming back on your power lines look like.  Is that noise caused by a SMPS running at 400 KHz?  Maybe you have system where the load is switched, or pulls current at a 10 KHz rate, like a radar system.

Answer (score 2):

More specific to your question.  That chart shows the attenuation of the filter - how much it reduces the noise - as a function of frequency.  That's the curvy line.  The straight line is from a Mil standard and specifies minimum attenuation required over a range of frequencies.

So it looks like this filter was designed for an application that is required to meet Mil-Std 220.  And this chart shows how the filter does against that requirement.

Answer (score 0):

The rating on filter is simply its transfer function: at x MHz it attenuates y dB and so on. The choice depends on what you are trying to pass.

In a EMC standard (like CISPR 12 for appliances) there are tables and/or curves saying, like: at 10 MHz you can't emit more than 60dBµV.

I measure my equipment and I see that, for example, at 10 MHz I'm outputting 100dBµV. So I'll chose a filter which, at 10 MHz, attenuates *at least* 40dB (with some safety margin).

A *big* issue is that usually filters are rated on a 50:50 ohm system (50 ohm impedance both on input and output). This isn't really representative of the actual impedences seen on the system. Good filter vendor also state the 1:100 and/or 100:1 filter response which are usually more representative.

At the end of the day it's mostly trial and error (how you mount the filter *will* influence it's response and noise often will bypass it someway)